# Acumatica - How to create Pivot Table in brand new screen

Tags: pivot-table, acumatica

I had seen and read some blog, document about using Pivot Table

But, the problems is I can't create Pivot Table because I can't find location of the screen in Sitemap.

I had added new Folder to storage all my new screen and when I choose selector Screen ID, I can't see it.

Have I missed any config to show it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the Generic Inquiry screen first, then in the upper right hand corner of the screen select Customization and then select Pivot Table.  The screen will then take you where you need to be with the Screen ID selected for you.